# MySQL query within a function in R

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I have created a function within r which generates a variable called `value`.
This value now needs to be inserted into the database for which I am using RMySQL package

but When I try to run the function I get the following error

```
 Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  unused arguments ("Aryan", ");")
```

The function is very long  and works well until the point where the variable generated is inserted into the database which is as under:

```
   pedd<-  function(breed, thattrait) {
    library(DBI)
     library(RMySQL)
    ...

    ...

     if (thattrait == "weight"){

        rs<- fn$dbSendQuery(con, 
                            "INSERT INTO mytable
                            (weight, race) 
                            VALUES ('$value', ", race, ");")
      } else {
        inser <-  paste0("Update mytable Set ",wean," = '$value' where race = ", race, "")
        rswean<- fn$dbSendQuery(con, inser)

      }
```

I am calling the function thus :

```
pedd("Aryan", "weight")
```

I cannot understand where I am wrong.

Comment: The statement argument in `dbSendQuery` is wrong. Your statement isn't correct. Use `paste` or `sprintf`.

Comment: Two points. `dbSendQuery ` is not recommended for data modification. You can use `dbSendStatement()` for data manipulation.

Comment: Tried changing that, it still is not working